# whats the syntax for params in a DB2 query

Tags: sql, db2, parameters

in MS-SQL I can do something like this

```
@myVar AS int;
@myVar = 12;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = @myVar;
```

this totally bombs out in DB2 - and I'm not sure if it's RDBMS specific or if it's because I've FUBAR'd the syntax...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Any error messages? normally you have to `declare` a variable.

Comment: What flavor of DB2 - iSeries or LUW?  There's even differences there...

Comment: I think this may help
--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216717/declare-a-variable-in-db2-sql#answer-6217730

Answer (score 0):

there are a limited number of things you can do dynamically in db2 sql compared to ms-sql. most of the syntax for what you appear to be attempting is reserved for use only in a procedure in db2. see the documentation here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004240.html for what you can do dynamically in db2.

if you are ok supplying parameter value on the fly just use
`select * from table where field = ?;` when you run it, it will ask you to supply a value for the parm.

Comment: not on the fly - but maybe I'll try that - I just have a series of queries I want to execute, that use similar filter data - I figured if I typed it once at the top - I would have to 'retype' it over and over when I want to reuse that script.

article was unhelpful - but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.NET Data Provider to connect to the DB2 Express-C, you can prefix bound SQL parameters with `@`.

I'm not sure about other DB2 environments, but common symbols used in other databases are: `:` and `?`, so it might be worth trying one of those.

Comment: interesting - I'm using the com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver (db2jcc.jar)
to connect thru DBeaver client. maybe I'll try IBM Control Center (that'll take forever!).. : didn't seem to help. thx